# HTML: Columns float everywhere

Tags: html, thumbnails

My website shows different articles each in one thumbnail. 
The problem is that the thumbnails seems to float everywhere. They are not aligned as it should be.

This is how my HTML code looks like.

```
  </head>
  <body>


        <div class="top-bar">
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="title-bar">
        </div>

        <br></br>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="300x200" src="[PIC]" width="300" />
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>
                                    [Name]
                                </h3>
                                <p>
                                    [Text]
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?action=DETAILE&id=[ID]">Go!</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

     </div>


</body>
```

The result is that the columns are not aligned. There are 3 columns next to each other, but the height differs, as well the position on the page. 
How can I solve this?

Now it looks like a staircase like in the code with the

I want:
     Box 1. Box2. Box 3.

Comment: Are you using a framework (such as Bootstrap)? What’s the layout you are expecting?

Comment: Yes I am using Bootstrap. What I expect is that each "box" (Thumbnail in HTML) is at the same row. Not it is done like a staircase.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 3 column layout will be like

```
<div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col3</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

To maintain equal height for all boxes assign equal height for all images,h3 and p tags(which are in the box)

Example snippet https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/store-product-layout

and in your html code there are many closing < /div> tags check html validations once.